# Flicker in refresh of JPanel with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox, flicker

I am trying to mimic a excel interface in Java. I have a paint method that paints the grid for me, paints all the cell values, then paints all my `JComboBox` objects, which are maintained as a `HashMap`.

Whenever I call my repaint function, I see a flicker between the combo boxes and the other painting functions.

Can someone please suggest methods that I can use to get rid of this flicker?

My code for the paint is as below:

```
public void paintCells(Graphics g) throws Exception {
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();

        if (this.graphics != null) g = this.graphics;

        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        Font oldFont = g.getFont();

        g.setColor(attr.panelBackgroudColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        paintHeader(g);

        paintGrid(g);

        int endRow = startRow + getCurrViewRowCount();
        int endCol = startCol + getCurrViewColCount();
        DisplayRows[] display = new DisplayRows[endCol-startCol+1];
        Thread[]  displays =  new Thread[endCol-startCol+1];

        for (int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++) {

            for (int j = startRow; j <= endRow; j++) {
                paintCell(g, i, j);
            }
         }

        paintSelectedCell(g);

        g.setColor(oldColor);
        g.setFont(oldFont);

        for (JComboBox dropDown : this.cellGrid.getDropDowns()) {
               orderedPair Pair =(orderedPair)                    this.getHashMapCellValues().get(this.getDropDowns().indexOf(dropDown));

               int col = Pair.getFirst();
               int row = Pair.getSecond();

               CellElement cellValue;
              try {
                  cellValue = new CellElement(col,row,dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString(),CellElement.CELLTYPE.NULL, CellElement.IOTYPE.INPUT);
                  this.getModel().addElement(cellValue);
              } catch (CellTypeException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(DisplayDropDownSpreadSheets.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
       dropDown.setBounds(this.getCellRect(this.getModel().getElement(col, row)));
               ((PricingCellModel)this.getModel()).setNull(col, row);

              dropDown.repaint();

    }
```

Paint header paints the header for my Excel interface, paint grid draws the lines and paintcell paints each cell in the interface.

Comment: easier is by using Renderer instead of, see Oracle tutorial How to use ComboBoxes

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).